# Systemd User services not starting

Tags: systemd, systemd-user

I am trying to get a user service to start at boot.

This is for Tableau on Linux (Ubuntu 19.04 Server, no gui)

Tableau creates a non-admin user to run it's services. and creates a systemd service at

`/etc/systemd/system/user@997.service` here it is

```
[Unit]
Description=User Manager for UID %i
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitNPROC=32768
User=%i
PAMName=systemd-user
Type=notify
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/loginctl enable-linger %i
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd --user
Slice=user-%i.slice
KillMode=mixed
Delegate=yes
TasksMax=infinity
Restart=always
RestartSec=15
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

if I just reboot the host and login as an unrelated user, and check the `systemctl status user@997.service` I see the problem is clearly with running `systemd --user` 
[image]

if I `sudo su - tableau` and try it myself, it either complains that there is no `/run/user/$(id -u)` directory, that $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't defined, or that it can't slice (I forget which and can't reboot the prod server to check it again right now) 
`journalctl -xe` reveals additional detail
[image]

So, pam_systemd can't see/list `/run/user/ID` so it doesn't set `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` so `systemd --user` running as tableau is pissed off,  which then causes `user@997` service to fail.

If I login at the console to the "tableau" user (ID 997) or even over SSH as it, it seems to create a "login" session instead, and `/run/user/997`, and the whole thing goes on down the line with the things being properly filled in and starting. After that, once the `/run/user/997` is created and the service tries to load once, the `enable-linger` in the `user@997` keeps it around fine, and I can log out with no problem and everything stays running fine, as it ought.

My thing is, as far as I can see from documentation (and presumably from Tableau's experience, as their init process set this up by default) this `User=997 ; PAMName=systemd-user` *should*  be working. and *should* be spawning a process as uid 997/tableau through systemd, but for whatever reason, this isn't defining the `/run/user/997` area

Once it's got the `/run/user/997` dir to find, it quickly loads the services, and then tableau heads off starting it's internal initialization processes

and then `user@997` status looks like this [image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the actual text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: Pictures can be uploaded to other server, it can be unreachable from some partially blocked network, which decrease the possibility of you getting an answer